# SQL Query Optimization Toad for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, toad

I am executing a query which is like

```
select a.col1
  ,a.col2
  ,b.col1
  ,b.col2
  ,c.col1
  ,c.col2
  ,d.col1
  ,d.col2
  ,e.col1
  ,e.col2
from table1 a,table2 b,table3 c,table4 d,table5 e
where a.col = b.col 
  and b.col = c.col 
  and a.col = e.col
  and c.col = d.col
  and d.col = e.col
```

This query is taking a lot of time to execute. 
I would like to know if there is any solution to optimize this query. 
I am using Toad for Oracle to execute.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax -- *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  That will at least make it more obvious if you have missed one or more `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your quick response. I am fairly new to this. Can you please give me a bit brief information. That would be a lot helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your query is written correctly, you want to be sure that each table has an index on `col`, the key used for the joining the tables.

That should fix your performance problems.

Comment: Yes the query is written correctly. It is giving results but taking a lot of time. That's the only issue right now.

Comment: @Anirudha.I you have 5 tables, 4 conditions are enough. You may get rid of  one condition like "a.col = b.col" or "b.col = c.col" ...